# Слетают CSS на Opencart при использовании https

Tags: ssl, opencart, https

Стоит принудительное использование https, через cloudflare, из-за этого сайт полностью "голый", в чём может быть проблема?
В конфигах вроде всё нормально, в админке стоит галочка напротив SSL

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://site.com/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://site.com/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://site.com/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'https://site.com/');
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В консоли браузера какие ошибки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Правим конфиги `config.php` :
  // HTTP
  define('HTTP_SERVER', 'https://example.com/');
  // HTTPS
  define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://example.com/');
  define('HTTP_IMAGE', 'https://example.com/image/');
- Указываем в настройках OC использовать https:
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- Делаем редирект с http на https, например в `.htaccess` :

  RewriteCond %{HTTP:SSL} !=1 [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*) https://site.com/$1 [L,R=301]
  Сразу после `RewriteBase /`
- Ищем в шаблоне и контенте на сайте где используются ссылки, на страницы и ресурсы, вида **http://** и исправляем на https://, относительные или //, по необходимости.